# wp_insert_post not inserting custom fields

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have created new columns in my table.
But whenever I try to insert values into it through wp_insert_post, it fails. All the other fields get their values correctly, except this one

```
'base_deluxe_price' => $_POST['deluxeRoomPrice'],
```

Full code below

```
wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_author' => get_the_author_ID(),
        'post_type' => 'hotels',
        'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['title']),
        'post_content' => $_POST['hotel_content'],
        'base_deluxe_price' => $_POST['deluxeRoomPrice'],
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    ), true);
```

Please help

It seems to work now when I use the code below. But the code runs on page load and on button click. Also, the custom values are not shown in wp-json.
Any help is much appreciated.

```
if (isset($_POST['saveHotel'])) {
        global $wpdb;
        $data_array = array(
            'post_author' => get_the_author_meta('ID'),
            'post_type' => 'hotels',
            'post_title' => $_POST['title'],
            'post_content' => $_POST['hotel_content'],
            'base_deluxe_price' => $_POST['deluxeRoomPrice'],
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );

        $table_name = 'wp_posts';

        $rowResult = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data_array, $format->NULL);
    }
```

Comment: If you read the documentation for the function. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/ it seems like you're looking for the hook. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```
$insert_post = array(
        'post_author' => get_the_author_ID(),
        'post_type' => 'hotels',
        'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['title']),
        'post_content' => $_POST['hotel_content'],
        'post_status' => 'publish'
  );

$post_id = wp_insert_post($insert_post);

add_post_meta($post_id, 'base_deluxe_price', $_POST['deluxeRoomPrice'], true);
```

Comment: I tried, not working. Still showing default value of 0.00

Comment: Your using ACF or default custom field?

Comment: I use ACF, but the new columns I added through database.

Comment: I only have the plugin installed and not using it yet.